# Is it true that $(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v} \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{v})$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields, differential-operators

I have seen that sometimes the Navier-Stokes equations are written with the term $(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v}$ expressed as $\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{v}$. However, is it true in general the following equality for any vector field $\mathbf{v}$?

$$(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v} \stackrel{?}{=} \mathbf{v} \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{v})$$

A couple of examples: in Batchelor's *An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics*, equation (2.1.2) defines the mass derivative of the velocity field (which is the LHS of the NS equation) as

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t}+\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u}$$

Whereas, in Landau-Lifschitz *Fluid Mechanics*, 2nd edition, the Navier-Stokes equation is written in equation (15.7) as

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t}+(\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{v}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p+\frac{\eta}{\rho} \Delta \mathbf{v}$$

On the other hand, in Wikipedia, it appears written both ways in the same article of the [Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations).

Comment: Notice that the RHS is a scalar function while the LHS is a vector field

Comment: @Udi Fogiel wouldn't the RHS be also a vector field? $\nabla \mathbf{v}$ is a second-order tensor field, so the dot product between $\mathbf v$ and $\nabla \mathbf{v}$ should give a vector field...

Comment: It seems like you are correct, I apologize for my mistake. this question is more interesting than i thought originally.

Answer (score 1):

The equality is true because both sides in index notation are
$$
v^\mu\nabla_\mu v^\nu\,.
$$
On the level of components this "multiplication" is associative. Then we sum over the repeated index $\mu$. What this describes is the directional derivative of the vector field $v$ into the direction of $v$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the *NRL Plasma Formulary*,

$$
\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{AB})=(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A})\mathbf{B}+(\mathbf{A}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{B}
$$

For $\mathbf{A=B=v}$, we have

$$
\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{vv})=(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v})\mathbf{v}+(\mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{v}
$$

I don't think I've ever seen the Navier-Stokes equations expressed as other than $\mathbf{v\cdot\nabla v}$, and clearly, from the above, this is not equal to $(\mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: I just edited the question to give a couple of examples where that term appears written in different ways in the Navier-Stokes equations.

Comment: @Invenietis The Wikipedia article seems to use the alternative form $(\mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{v}$ for incompressible flow, but I can't tell how they got it. Can you?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Cye Waldman's answer in case it is useful to anyone.

He is, in essence, correct. However, in the case of an incompressible fluid, say water or air at low velocities ($M < 0.3$):

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{u} = 0
\end{equation}

That's the incompressible continuity (conservation of mass) equation.

Therefore, using (7) on page 4 of *NRL PLASMA FORMULARY*:

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \left( \boldsymbol{u}\boldsymbol{u} \right) = \left( \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{u} \right) \boldsymbol{u} + \boldsymbol{u} \cdot \left( \nabla \boldsymbol{u} \right) = 0 + \boldsymbol{u} \cdot \left( \nabla \boldsymbol{u} \right) = \boldsymbol{u} \cdot \left( \nabla \boldsymbol{u} \right)
\end{equation}